# finding the most efficient path between places

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have to find the most efficient route between 5 places, there is a cost associated with each possible step from 1 place to another. This leaves me with 10 possible steps to take, i have to find the cheapest possible route to reach all places.

I have tried to use intlinprog in matlab to find the most efficient route however i then ran into the problem that i couldnt have the steps be either 1 or 0, and therefore get combinations of the costs of several steps, as well as having one of my constraints being an equality instead of an inequality.

I then tried to use a for loop but there i still have the problem that i dont know how to have my variables (the steps) be either 1 or 0

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Can you show what you have tried so far ?
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask]. You might also want to learn about [example].

Comment: What is the question? You describe your homework goal, and describe what you tried, but you don’t ask a question.

Comment: Have a look at Dijkstra's algorithm - some variant of that will probably work for you.

Comment: There are algorithms for the all-pairs shortest path problem (Floyd-Warshall algorithm). Of course using a loop around a single-pair shortest path algorithm should also work.